# Send POST value using Ajax from a button in HTML/PHP

Tags: php, ajax, forms, post, button

** I found a way that works - will paste it underneath all this text**

I want to use Ajax to send a hidden value containing a variable from PHP, using a button.

I can send the value no problem, if I define it:

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
    $.post("results.php",
    {
    id:"1000"
    },
    function(data,status){
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
    });
    });
    </script>
```

Then i can process the $_POST['id'] variable on the page results.php.

But how do I instruct Ajax to send the hidden value in an HTML form button?  My HTML is contained within a PHP print_r instruction and looks like this:

```
    print("<form id='form' method='post' action=''>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value=$strTweet2>
    <input type='submit' value='RT'></form>");
```

Thanks for any help Overflowers. I've been reading through other peoples issues, and learned to send a value if I define it, I just can't figure out how to send the value from a button.

** So I've got this to work but only in HTML, when I apply it in a foreach it will only give me the first value in the array, but I will ask another question I guess. This script will send a single hidden value from a form button **

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
    function submitForm() {
    $.ajax({type:'POST', url: 'results.php', data:$('#ContactForm').serialize()});
    return false;
    }
    </script>
```

HTML

```
    <form id='ContactForm' onsubmit='return submitForm();'>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='1000'>
    <input type='submit' value='Post it!'>
```

Comment: For starters, don't use print_r. Use echo, and put the HTML in "double quotes"

Comment: is id the only field in the form?

Comment: Yes andrew, it's just one value that I want to put into the hidden field in a button. I saw people using serialise when they had more than one field, but I couldn't figure out how to modify that to let me send only one set of data.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, do not use print_r() as this function is meant for debugging. Use print() instead.

In jQuery you can access hidden field value by field name like this:

```
$('input[name=id]').val()
```

but you can give it id and do this:

```
$('#id').val()
```

... and put your string into double quotes:

```
print("<form id='form' method='post' action=''>
<input type='hidden' name='id' value=$strTweet2>
<input type='submit' value='RT'></form>").
```

Edit: Working example how to select hidden field value by name and post it using jQuery .post()

```
<?php

if (!empty($_POST['id'])){
    print(json_encode(array('id' => $_POST['id'])));
    exit();
}

?>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('input[type=submit]').click(function(){ 
        $.post("", { id:$('input[name=id]').val() }, function(data,status){ 
            alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status); 
        });
        return false;
    }); 
});

</script>

<form id="form" method="post" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="hidden_value">
    <input type="submit" value="RT">
</form>
```

Just copy it into .php file and point your browser there :)

Comment: Thanks Rauli, I've changed to print() like you and Jeffman mentioned. So I was thinking that the reason I would have to use Ajax is to post the variable to another page, but using .val how do I post the contents to that page? I'm reading http://api.jquery.com/val/ but this is not making sense as to to POSTing the data to my results.php page.

Comment: Replace id:"1000" with id:$('input[name=id]').val() , so it uses input field value (instead of static string "1000").

Comment: Thanks, again Rauli. I tried that and get no response from results.php page at all. Code now looks like:
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
$.post("results.php",
    {
    id:$('input[name=id]').val() 
    },
    function(data,status){
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
    });
    });
HTML is exactly as in your example.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice it yesterday, but your .click() selector didn't select anything, as there wasn't <button> html element on the page. I edited my answer to show working example.